# Multiple Notice: Undefined variable errors when I call a function

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

I'm trying to write a PHP function `Insertdata($table,$field,$data)` that will insert some data. Here is what I've got so far:

**insertdata.php**

```
<?php
  include('connection.php');

  function Insertdata($table,$field,$data){

    $field_values= implode(',',$field);
    $data_values=implode(',',$data);

    $sql="INSERT into". " ".$table." ".$field_values. "VALUES(".$data_values.")";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
  }
?>
```

The call of this function happens in another page:

**sample.php**

```
<?php
  include('../model/insertdata.php');
  $table="country";
  $field_values=array("country_name","status");
  $data_values=array("usa",'1');
  $sample=Insertdata($table,$field,$data);
  if($result)
  {
    echo "inserted";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "not inseterd";
  }
?>
```

Whenever I call the function above the following error gets thrown and no data is inserted:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: field in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/view/sample.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined variable: data in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/view/sample.php on line 6
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/model/insertdata.php on line 6
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/model/insertdata.php on line 7
INSERT into country VALUES()
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/model/insertdata.php on line 10
Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/model/insertdata.php on line 10
```

I'm new to PHP and in the process of learning. I need some advice how to get this working.

Comment: yes there is no field named `$field` & `$data`

Comment: It appears that `$field` & `$data` are never defined. It does look like you defined `$table`, `$data_values`, & `$field_values`. Typo?

Comment: 9 people answered and not a single soul mentioned this function is outright dangerous, allowing any kind of SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `sample.php` change

```
$sample=Insertdata($table,$field,$data);
```

to

```
$sample=Insertdata($table,$field_values,$data_values);
```

that will fix most of those errors as `$field` and `$data` aren't defined in `sample.php`. The final error has to do with $conn which is presumably defined in `connection.php`

Comment: thank you i have changed now its throwing only one error                                                                                                            Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /var/www/html/online_test/admin/model/insertdata.php on line 10

Comment: That error is telling you that $conn isn't an object. The problem is most likely a scope issue. Right inside of the function definition at the very top add `global $conn;`. If that doesn't fix it, then it is an error within `connection.php`

Comment: Also, your `if($result)` will need to be `if($sample)` or it will always echo `not inserted` as `$result` is never defined (scope issue).

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty wrong with this code, first:

```
$table="country";
$field_values=array("country_name","status");
$data_values=array("usa",'1');
$sample=Insertdata($table,$field,$data);
```

`$field` and `$data` don't exist. Make sure you are passing the correct variable names.

Also, `$conn` is not known within `Insertdata()` context, you have to either pass this variable as parameter too or make it a global.

Also, the SQL syntax is all wrong. `INSERT into country country_name,statusVALUES(usa,1)` is not valid SQL. Make sure you are formatting your query properly, and also that you are filtering against [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

For example:

```
$fields = implode('`, `', $field);
$values = implode("', '", array_map(function ($val) use ($conn) { return $conn->real_escape_string($val); }, $data));
$sql = "INSERT INTO `{$table}` (`{$fields}`) VALUES ('{$values}')";
```

Answer (score -1):

You just mis-configured your variables when calling the function.

```
$table="country";
$field_values=array("country_name","status");
$data_values=array("usa",'1');
$sample=Insertdata($table,$field_values,$data_values);
```

Answer (score -1):

There are so many issues in your code, first of all here is the modified code:

**Modified Function:**

```
<?
function Insertdata($table,$field,$data)
{
    $field_values= implode(',',$field);
    $data_values=implode("','",$data);

    $sql= "INSERT INTO $table (".$field_values.") 
    VALUES ('".$data_values."') ";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
}
```

**Modified Function Calling:**

```
$table = "country";
$field = array("country_name","status");
$data = array("usa",'1');
$result = Insertdata($table,$field,$data);
if($result)
{
    echo "inserted";
}
else
{
    echo "not inseterd";
}
?>
```

**Issues:**

- `Insertdata()` function you are using VALUES as a simple string, you need to use quotes between string value otherwise it will display like this `VALUES (usa,1)` this should be `VALUES ('usa','1')` or `VALUES ('usa',1)`.
- You are using `undefined variable` in function parameters `$field`, `$data`, both of them not defined, this should be `$field_values`, `$data_values`.
- Third, you are using undefined variable `$result` in success, failure condition this should be `$sample` not `$result`.
- You are getting Fatal error because you are not using `$conn` in function param, limited scope

Answer (score -2):

In all of these answers you got a similar error that is
1) Notice: Undefined variable: conn
2) Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null
These two errors come to avoid them try this:

**function:**

```
<?php 
function Insertdata($table,$field,$data,$conn)
{
    $field_values= implode(",",$field);
    $data_values=implode(",",$data); 

    $sql= "INSERT INTO $table (".$field_values.") VALUES (".$data_values.")";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
}
if($result){
    echo "inserted";
} else {
    echo "not inseterd";
}
?>
```

**function calling:**

```
<?php 
$table = "country";
$field = array("country_name","status");
$data = array("'usa'","'1'");
$result = Insertdata($table,$field,$data,$conn);

?>
```

Use this code to avoid those two errors.

Answer (score -2):

```
    function InsertRecordToTable($tableName='',$fieldNames='')
    {
        $fields  = implode(',', array_keys($fieldNames));
        $values  = implode(',', mysqli_escape_string(array_values($fieldNames)));
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO ".$tableName.'('.$fields.') Values '.'('.$values.')';
    }
```

Try This Function Example with Argument Passed

```
$field['FirstName'] = 'Manoj';
$field['LastName'] = 'Kiran';
$field['Age'] = '21';
Insertrecord('testtable',$field);
```

It is working fine to insert record

Answer (score -2):

Try This:

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','kailash');


   $table = "country";

   $field = array("country_name","status");
   $data = array("usa",'1');

   $field_values= implode(',',$field); 
   $data_values = implode("','",$data);

   $sql = "INSERT INTO $table($field_values)VALUES('$data_values')";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
```